# How to align DIV vertically & horizontally center

Tags: css

Can someone help me to get div id "loader" to float in the center of div class "Window". Thanks.

```
<div id="someid" class="Window">
   <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE* I need to center it in the absolute middle of a block. Lets say class "Window" was 400px high. How do I get "loader to float in the center (height/width) of that?

Comment: I need to center it in the absolute middle of a block. Lets say class "Window" was 400px high. How do I get "loader to float in the center (height/width) of that?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sfKR2/ I'm going to edit my answer..

Comment: Close Fabian. SenorAmor got it close to what I needed. Thanks tho :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the following CSS to "loader":

- position: relative
- top: 50%
- margin: -{E}px auto auto auto

where {E} is half the height of "loader"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you do margin: -25% auto auto auto and not care how tall loader is?

Comment: Not if you still want it to be centered vertically.  The `top: 50%` moves the interior div down 50% of the height of its parent div.  Then, the `margin: -{E}px` part moves the interior div back up.  We move it half of its height so it stays centered vertically.

Comment: This does not appear to work well when used inside a wrapper which has the width and height set to 100%.

Answer (score 3):

```
#someid.Window{
   // give this some width
   width: 100%
}

#loader{
    // give width and margin auto on the sides
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I need to center it in the absolute middle of a block. Lets say class "Window" was 400px high. How do I get "loader to float in the center (height/width) of that?

Comment: k, can you change your question to mention that you want to center the `#loader` div horizontally *and* vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#loader {
  width: 123px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

This will make your left and right margins be calculated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sfKR2/

```
#someid {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
#loader {
    position: relative;
    height:80px;
    width: 80px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40px; /* half of the height */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

write this:

```
.window{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    background:red;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}
#loader{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dxPfz/